# How to make non-secure cookie default for HTTPS session

Tags: jsf, cookies, jsf-2, https, glassfish

In my application, the 1st page the user access can be the `Login.xhtml` page which is a secure HTTPS page. Hence, when I check the cookie on Chrome, it was initially created for `Secure connections only`. As a consequence, after the user successfully log in, I cannot use that cookie to redirect him to any non-secure pages.

I'd be very grateful if you could show me how I can make my cookie a non-secure one even on the 1st HTTPS request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sun-web.xml change the cookie property using the cookieSecure property

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sun-web-app>
<session-config>
  <cookie-properties>
    <b><property name="cookieSecure" value="false"/></b>
  </cookie-properties>
</session-config>
```

The following are explanations of each value you can set:

**true**: Any JSESSIONID cookies created by the container on behalf of the web application will be marked as secure.

**false**: Any JSESSIONID cookies created by the container on behalf of the web application will be marked as non-secure.

**dynamic**: A JSESSIONID cookie created by the container on behalf of the web application will inherit its security setting from the request that initiated the correspoding session: If the session was initiated by an HTTPS request, its JSESSIONID cookie will be marked as secure, and will remain non-secure otherwise. This is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Set the attribute `requireSSL="False"` in the service `web.config`.

```
httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" lockItem="true"
```